# File location issue in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

I am trying to access an external file to use in my App.js file , called scrollv.js
which is in a folder called tutorials . But it returns

> *Can't resolve './tutorial/scrollv.js' in '/Users/bet/Desktop/PROJECT/mern/react-native/project/tutorial/learning'*

Here's [my file strucrture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJKac.png),  [my scrollv.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPjv8.png) and my [App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87x5E.png)

Every time react re-enders my page sometimes I get an error like the one above or the predicted output which **only** appears on the web.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Your app.js image is not loading, but it would be better to copy and paste the code into a `code block` directly in your question, rather than linking images.

Comment: Please add your code as a [mcve] so others can run it if needed to debug the issue.